# How to check if a template typename is the same as another type but ignoring template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, c++-concepts, c++23

I want to make a library that provides units of measurements, such as length, mass, etc as types. I know such libraries probably exist already, but I want to learn how to do such a thing myself. I took inspiration from `std::chrono::duration`, which uses `std::ratio`, so I use that approach as well. But I ran into the problem that there is a lot of code duplication, particularly for math operation such as `+`.

My approach is that I have a `Measurement` base class from which I derive individual measurements such as `Length` or `Mass`. A lot of the code is the same between those individual measurements, such as `operator+`, which takes two measurements and adds the values, correcting for the ratio between them. For example I can add 5 meters to 12 ft. But I can not put it in the base class because if I did that I could add a mass to a length, which is nonsense and the very thing I am trying to rectify in the first place.

My solution would be to put those things in the base class, but add a requires clause that prohibits the `other`'s type from being different from the type of the object that is being added to.
The problem with that is that I still want a Length unit to be addable to another Length unit, but with a different `std::ratio` template parameter. But c++ treats them as different types, and so if I used `std::same_as`, it would fail, preventing me to add 5 meters to 12 feet because `Length<float, std::ratio<1>>` (1 meter) and `Length<float, std::ratio<100'000, 328'084>>` (1 feet) are different types.

How can I make sure that

```cpp
using Kilogram = Measurements::Mass<float>;
using Meter = Measurements::Length<float>;
using Feet = Length<float, std::ratio<100'000, 328'084>>;

Meter m{5};
Kilogram kg{45};

// m + kg; // should error
Meter m2{Feet{22}}; // should work
Feet f1 = m2; // should work
// Feet f2 = 12; // should error
Meter m3 = m2 + ft; // should work
// Kilogram kg2 = m2; // should error
```

But without having all the operation overloads and constructors in Mass and Length duplicated?

Here is an example of the problem

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ratio>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace Measurements
{

template <typename T>
concept IsArithmetic = requires { requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>; };

template <typename R>
concept IsRatio = requires {
    {
        R::num
    };
    {
        R::den
    };
};

template <IsArithmetic Rep, IsRatio Factor = std::ratio<1, 1>>
class Measurement
{
  private:
    Rep m_value {};

  public:
    using REP    = Rep;
    using FACTOR = Factor;
    static const auto NUM {Factor::num};
    static const auto DEN {Factor::den};

    explicit Measurement(Rep value) noexcept : m_value {value}
    { /* Empty */
    }

    // C-TORS (copy & move) and assignment (copy & move) overloads for
    // Measurements<Rep, Factor> argument (defaulted with = default) and
    // template <typename Rep2, Factor2> Measurements<Rep2, Factor2> argument

    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr auto Value() const noexcept -> Rep
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    // Can't do this, it would allow adding kilograms to meters
    /*
    template <typename Rep2, typename Factor2>
    constexpr auto operator+ (const Measurement<Rep2, Factor2>& other) const
    {
        using Adjustment              = std::ratio_divide<Factor2, Factor>;
        constexpr const double FACTOR = static_cast<double>(Adjustment::num) / static_cast<double>(Adjustment::den);

        return Measurement<Rep, Factor> {
          static_cast<Rep>(static_cast<double>(this->Value()) + (static_cast<double>(other.Value()) * FACTOR))
        };
    }

    template <typename Rep2, typename Factor2>
    constexpr auto operator+ (Measurement<Rep2, Factor2>&& other) const
    {
        using Adjustment              = std::ratio_divide<Factor2, Factor>;
        constexpr const double FACTOR = static_cast<double>(Adjustment::num) / static_cast<double>(Adjustment::den);

        return Length<Rep, Factor> {
          static_cast<Rep>(static_cast<double>(this->Value()) + (static_cast<double>(std::move(other).Value()) * FACTOR))
        };
    }
    */
};


template <typename Rep, typename Factor = std::ratio<1, 1>>
class Length final : public Measurement<Rep, Factor>
{
  public:
    Length() noexcept : Measurement<Rep, Factor>() {}
    explicit Length(Rep value) noexcept : Measurement<Rep, Factor>(value) {};

    Length(const Length<Rep, Factor>& other) noexcept : Measurement<Rep, Factor>(other) {};
    Length(Length<Rep, Factor>&& other) noexcept : Measurement<Rep, Factor>(std::move(other)) {};

    auto operator= (auto&& other) noexcept -> Length<Rep, Factor>&
    {
        Measurement<Rep, Factor>::operator= (std::forward(other));
        return *this;
    };

    template <typename Rep2, typename Factor2>
    explicit Length(const Length<Rep2, Factor2>& other) noexcept : Measurement<Rep, Factor>(other) {};

    template <typename Rep2, typename Factor2>
    explicit Length(Length<Rep2, Factor2>&& other) noexcept
            : Measurement<Rep, Factor>(std::move(other)) {};

    //NOLINTNEXTLINE (modernize-use-override)
    virtual ~Length() final = default;

    template <typename Rep2, typename Factor2>
    constexpr auto operator+ (const Length<Rep2, Factor2>& other) const
    {
        using Adjustment              = std::ratio_divide<Factor2, Factor>;
        constexpr const double FACTOR = static_cast<double>(Adjustment::num) / static_cast<double>(Adjustment::den);

        return Length<Rep, Factor> {
          static_cast<Rep>(static_cast<double>(this->Value()) + (static_cast<double>(other.Value()) * FACTOR))
        };
    }
};

template <typename Rep, typename Factor = std::ratio<1, 1>>
class Mass final : public Measurements::Measurement<Rep, Factor>
{
     // copy paste of Length
};

}    // namespace Measurements
```

A complete example can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmAMzSAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8dJ2mA7pQgRMxASZPn5ctpj2%2BQy19QSFYZHRsQm2dQ1N2a0Ko73B/SWD5QCUtqhexMjsHOZxwcjeWADUJnFuTlPEmKzH2CYaAILbu/uYRyfETPnXtw/xT16HxzcBAAnolMAB9AjvQgKL73R4MPb/F6AryOWiEYFwh73ZhsBSJJgbA4AWUuCjWmDYglh8IA7FZ4fcCFTEgYWa8gaDGKwXgAVbFoRGYRIEA4ASQUd2IhAQbEcyFeABEDhcAI5ePAXBRHBmqzAarWYHVTdAgEB4BTg%2Bqy%2BV4ZDggBugIFcRucQsuqVx0ZOLuLJYbI%2BKJOILBeJeACVBQINqKJQpIx8nMr9YbtbrfQds5nvjn8wdI%2BaGD48zmTHTvR6y9mK1mC9miyAsAwa16fd8K1Xfd8A0GOYDJdLbZgFYWRaQE0n8gcAGJEojEVOm83vT4nVoHLhfN3fPZMBQ6skHynUgidhllxIyx3BkBtyMig4sJ1iLwoy%2BVjtMu7ZxJeCIMWQe97nzLxUiMQtsGUfNjhVR9Em/X8c3A4JgDnO43D5AB5SNU3nBwSCQ/MpmTRUhSmA4mDRVADlCOQSUzAjF2LUsv2rUCc1IscKLFaiiAOJVsFCJiFxIc0Wy7JC20wVQ2XtQhSXJU9GAICAEIOW9vEwRYDgYVBZLjMUQGfV9tMzLT3ykzjaz1AB6AAqA5sEDEEDgcuy22sv022PCkLjPCBdIbELQrC8KIsiqLyziFUsCoajaHPDjkOzPyVMECBeKUk8AtUwEEMnZiiN3MwADYDlQAgEGiXT9MMkUxWi5rYNig54sS5L6zS5S8sy9K%2BuStxCrnMTiC%2BcrzAqqqauIOqDNUIyWuWhs4PazAEq8JLiJzfjaNQME1xKlUsoESiBqpfKThG4rxtK6bqtqvSFqWgBaa4cv8y7BAKidRsIu6bnK1MOq2rq2z2yrDo%2BY6DggC6z1%2BxIirGiayqmyrHrm56Gvjd63U%2BjKhpu1H7tWtrQe2lL80dLUCC8MQDgAPwR1SgpxxbGpW7meYLNbKfBn98z7dkQy5cNeXHRIzEnMMeTYf7FzMbF81k%2BTkEU1nMuyrXiZFGXFZIZWyZmp76s50UvMvGyC1QyC7nQbRwIIM9orWlcQDXJxwXwWmsEBW6DdunduoLXi1aXbL0FWQCXlnTCcLw926gVcFRCmQFo4A%2BhrggB2namM9WJYXS7IObj7TTg8hqz2Pc/z52i%2BbRhFh2hsX0sl5eeXFPK/TvXELdCAK4dfvM5jnOh9N4gADoADU30wILdKc%2BOsNw1vqfLL8hZzEXg05OWIylg2j8lwOVZzNWgM13rvrU3WkaDsbjaB9Hgen%2BbcfPG26zbMCILoQboXVSbs2oey9qgH2eA/aYADi/FGAMQ7/xzOHOSkczpilrvQDC68k7gN7qPau49s5wKHsAl2qli6l3LoQquGcTjYLIdgPOjtG5UObgwTeod8wd0Xt3HuZF6ED1ziPYRJC65Dw9iwVAjol6f3novZe7lcGJ24Vbb0u9sz7wHKGbkx8EKn30efF%2Bl9syQwOtEGGd0To6zvoja6%2BtEFKzRpjWaX8LZinxtgQmg0kbOJKm/K2PCUKAIOBQ12UVk5mk9smKBvs8D%2BxOIHAJgM25h0wRHA4UcJ5xwTrhQRqcx6MNyfXNhIDBDUIOGXMRxS3BMLKQXShlTOHqJtrwsy74BHJyEXUhCoi6F1IaVPLGijtLKNXvkyMbTUoFguPTYgDB3LVUtOk7ybYdFizPgrQxstjEKwvruG2FjoaLjWvDexV1hpOMNsQV%2BU0Mafw5m9D6j9HHI1uWjYJKDsx2yAeU5pTVIrRNXHE6BsD4EA2fkg3cW8GxoOvNkzB7VcmqIKT0opxCSmkMaewlpJYS7VNob0rF9TSnkIBU3FsMzQp8PMt3DFfdSX9KkYM0lwyWHSNkfIrGiwxnvgmWi6Z6T8zzLWEshyKzYRwvbFoo4ABWKwir9L4AUKIYg6ATDyu9NqtsCKlyQwXuM3S2VzYvIJv03%2B1tZmitHOK0ync1k7weOxHsP5OzMlZKLQ%2B%2Byox/W2XHMaPcYmQMBJubcsKbj3H3IeA4ARGDAGqgcGgzBaAHBMv%2BQC9pfH338Z8o5Lr6yZqAiBWZ8ajDVXZmarmJk3nXI%2BcHIeuk/7OtVnJG%2BYpy2JoQOpJ8ncPFLVrZcn67zUm537bmZ1bYu2VuyjOhAebG1vzcWbF6Nac0OPrWOkZ7jJ2aLLQmyt87F2kyCR/Xlzz111pJjCzlBAYkyLkRAT%2BzbPz7ohjRKGVizltQgHtB557d3Vrxh9Y9o781BKtSEnquVc3gaXeaSxR0bFww9vwYgAB3eo6Bn28ppSFMVizlkIFWTK9ZNtNk%2Boljsm5Abbn3JttfBSnbD09rnaxp%2BqT7mAdXd/dNG6rk3p/Swp5Lb30Ua9QfQEdHdkHDo4cqNsymMaxYxWntYH63QpcfdR5F7gM/xtSFIdsHN1CcCcPe95pH08vca%2BqwU6bZ2TsqEbCARxShD5KEbAAANPkbmvNwxkVgRZeAABemBXrgQi9y4gMosCtxtrTBoDM01M3nezFNjN%2BYbU6tJCTgZvXSd9SfPZ1HA1QrMUihgUwsknO/URSwcN2Nqc4/R1xTzeLfPaaEtC4TKWgKiQQkNYKElJLcCkiDIrUGZPQVVyiTChWFKZQwslOKKVNKbgSmhtT2XkpYREjh1K8uGezIRpZGmzOA1zN1kibKVssrvSSlbHKIBSu8UagVixm2NYs09mue3cOzX5UvL7Ki15qISyd9sZGHOzMo0VsrJW5PFYU3qmbiK6vIdek15FF2bmo549jTrUGfn6gWedjj8HT2ZggJKkjChvuekB9EFRO37silzq9LgX2pIw/E3DyTui3BDhlNVO0ipbp8m5JV/VVFP1IesU5U61WxSS%2Bl8DBKAMTWYK61Ds7cbKdbog5mN71wPsg9Z3dkRQ9NeLlbq6jRHqBcFakycEXI4xxq7BDL9HBr5enJIGXZXlEvdwI12NbXKvdehX13jht1O6ym7dOb9mNSrdI1zrbkg9vuyO7lU5g4OElTYRMgrxcZcMOygE4IA43ipZtgL0XkvX7kPWDgg3suTfS8B%2BIPjfd%2BZG/YWL93%2BrxAHLt8c53ofzey%2BB7WhpAQtAsST8L9PkfrfYoT5dbnn88O9GI5GvJ093xMeK5xyrhMw4xejmzf%2B4GtAEAKEnM17tJ7b0Y2II/3Sde4/bsU3/G2fXT/HUJyB/aVHsWHPfcWeWP1D5I/AGYNUFdcNwcNHcRTGNI8A8HUTLNNDNbObNXWBQc0a9P6JdC8ItfA4CXyLAqtNdeMYzL6M8IgkAEg%2BPW9dmMTGSdtZjUkGgjSCdfTfjQg4g4dAeP/CACdTglKagw8YPMUEkLAt/YTXTIDOg4yavAgZg1g8Q0TN9dJBQ2Qgw6VI3MgyaQnAdK9UQrQ0QpQ8zLlJ9F9PdY7fMU/H9E6O/d%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%2BEnAgTiTDUnAjXdHdEdLCVnEwFHDClTMN3TMzIIGzMs1iWQK4A0A0DAA4GbI0EnDiDMAAA5WyNBuzJA0D0kUTQh%2BJ7QxASQ6AQwVQ0yMyszaFhtGzuz5UDYCzkE5UUSABpOgVAYAd4FgFgVqFUF0twasj4dcv0fMMkFkJcEKQ8usLgZWB3G2Us8s0KKgMUOseVDQVUm2UctEcc2gScnBBgFgPATMLgGeOkWcX8y8riestANETkQEZ8eU5tE4FC8wMwe8xrLC5Ck4ZNAgNC/CtwI4MwMwD81MPCwEFCk4siz0D8vlcUkisi7CrVNwVsci9JD2RCz8jCgij84imigirCyi7Hai/i0ilgISyS1i%2B8tqCStwWisS58JipRdCpSkS8ij89izi42UOHi1YPizS0i0CvAGSky1isy2vLcZslRRSlCwS5i4S0i0SvilUBygiiAay7HJsjQFRRiiyzC8isy3SrCr4nqG858MwTMUK582ZQypClyvSMCoKrSswaytaTyqSswNK1y8ilgMKri10/Mf8hUCcqclKvAGKusa8lnOsMwdsqSeK27GJXilirCxq5s%2BSjy8ilisy3K5y2SrC0K%2BVDi8KkqnMbcjMvc1gQ8gAa3QjrEkHlVgq1MWvoufHSQ2ohMWoirJ3tR/JlXdN2I82EiVADMuGDNDIxBBAjKYCjOQBjIGGIHjPpH3Q4GWFoE4HlV4D8DbN4FQE4CUssAhIUFWHWBRHiB4FIAIE0E%2BuWHmpAHlTKhnm7IAE55UVz4huzuyNB5V0aypCb9BOBJA/r4bSAgaOBeAiCOy4aAblg4BYAYBEAUBUBAwpyyAKBToOb6AYhgAFBmBEgFAEAqpSAsBaYNg548BMAMNsJwxOAYaaAkpogiCIAIgKbQzmBiBgRFbeAtb6hgRsIIhtAqh6aYa0ADzVJsIGAl8KasAIgvBgA3AxBaAiDuBeAsATSjBxAAbxajRqg5F3atBSBZIqg0RNgQ7LT2gKaMQIh3gdaPAsAKaoQ8AWA9blh0yHqFBpbZb5bGA9aZBBARAxB2ApAi75AlA1AKbdA4h9BDBjA29LB9A8AIgiDIBlgDpOh3bXpsI4ha90JXpTQ4JTBQbLB4ha8AB1V2qe2SKEJgKesEYMwQbNV6SephV6a8dmqqdIKe9DE05KJUGKte/ej4GMxfQgKxNNE%2BkgA%2BoevAYAEIdAEIWNG%2B4gO%2B4EMweaqeksWgWgV6YLDaaIRgYkNetOkoggV6BKP%2B6qYgVYYABdWKY%2ByesCw8NCV6P4LAABrUHUNehQSvAgZABAABj4pKKerwEsJQdATe%2BoXkKKteih4INIMQC49AKeikYAYAY0SBj4VOx2lkEe5FNe121AJ68LOBqekR0QKeoUORV63ek%2BucyB2R1WhRye1IR%2B16FR%2BRgQKe9ALwdWYMah%2BOwwIh40PRgxoCIxrRgQNhte%2BewMTwWYXByes8yBg0FLdhhAIM1ADDQRwMZMWOV6DM0Qa%2Byeih%2BKchyhzAahk05AOBlx/uV6DURmNepJlhx%2BuCc4e0LxSemawC64xIKe1BwBEh/cSBarKei4fRhgZeyBrAPYFx0iZAeazeuBlkBAqB5p1prejpxcWvJewwBUV6aIOB162e2LY6QZlexUNe0Z46Ih%2BoIegCNVGUUUFx%2BZmxX%2B/%2BwBqgYB4UCZsZuCJhyBuwKgQ546cBjtKB122B%2BBxBo%2Bi5mxVB%2BgIM9B4IFsXuXRuZyZ55y0UpkxjYDZ35uCFgMGS0FOe%2Be6%2BJlIJ5rJjxkBiLZIS0uF2KM7V6OWVFpUMFpKe0bx4gQGuR249uoKNoDodIFwWp8YFoUO2pvoYoUoHIFINIAQalplvIdIell6vQSoaoAQboMYTwZoHl9oM2moaYLl%2BYGISYaYNlmVnoSVxl7nFYNYDYCQL6n68mv2qmg4VQbssqV6MqSQA4YAZARUV7YgCh%2Ba3SCAXAQgEgMiuIbnXgemrQL7UgGqIMwYUlpGsqXKswSQbsrsswKQOkMqeVJsmWb6jgMm0gdO%2BVbsmeOIZNlN1NlN6Qf6kOqmmmkAOm%2BGxmlmiAJAIy/8Ws7my2xITm0ctgTgPVg1o1k1s1rcf13gGJ%2B1uLPQfgYu0Jsu6QLtyulQdQP22u0gDDd4RIfNkmjgX60gTNwGzgbCNEUtyqc5utw1410181qEK1m1jwXm%2Bq%2BIOIRYF1/N5YT14LSgDVmN3gdOyQSCsqB9x9p9x9ukWdim7N2wXN2G090gJGyQOIGeJsyQSQOkMNrgLgdGyQDQMwdGqduILVrNzgE9hmq9swBD%2Bd6m79lD0gOR1IZwSQIAA%3D%3D) on Godbolt.

As you can see it's extremely verbose. How can I stay type safe but cut back on the code duplication, particularly the operator overloads?

In the best case I would simply inherit from Measurements and not need to do anything but add special overloads, such as dividing an Area by a Length should return a Length.

**Edit 1**

Having no idea what I'm doing, I tried this

```cpp
template <template <IsArithmetic Rep1, IsRatio Factor1> typename Outer1, template <IsArithmetic Rep2, IsRatio Factor2> typename Outer2>
concept HasSameOuterType = requires {
    requires std::same_as<Outer1<Rep1, Factor1>, Outer2<Rep1, Factor1>>;
};
```

However it says:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'Rep1' (clang undeclared_var_use)

Just comparing `Outer1` and `Outer2` also gives an error:

> Use of template template parameter 'Outer1' requires template arguments (clang template_missing_args)

Comment: See a previous [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180043/handle-variadic-templates-for-general-case-mixed-types-and-non-types) on stackoverflow. It's related to C++17, but I think also applies to solutions/limitations in C++23.

Comment: This is starting to look a lot like black magic to me. I just now started to look into this template stuff because concepts are supposed to make it easier to read, write and understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept `HasSameOuterType` itself is not that difficult to write. You can use type deduction with a lambda in your requirement.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
concept HasSameOuterType = requires (T t, U u) {
    []<template <typename R, typename F> typename Outer, typename Rep1, typename Factor1, typename Rep2, typename Factor2>
    (Outer<Rep1, Factor1>&, Outer<Rep2, Factor2>&){}(t, u);
};
```

The concept can be further adapted to your need (e.g. taking into account references and cv-qualifiers, or requiring `Rep1` to satisfy `IsArithmetic` in the lambda). I'm keeping it simple here.

The following tests pass:

```cpp
    static_assert(Measurements::HasSameOuterType<Meter, Feet>);
    static_assert(!Measurements::HasSameOuterType<Meter, Kilogramm>);
    static_assert(Measurements::HasSameOuterType<std::pair<int, double>, std::pair<float, char>>);
    static_assert(!Measurements::HasSameOuterType<std::pair<int, double>, std::tuple<int, double>>);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/do76oY1rc