# Check if class is of template specialization (with template arguments like bool or int)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, type-traits

Based on the answers from [How to tell if template type is an instance of a template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012938/how-to-tell-if-template-type-is-an-instance-of-a-template-class#44013030) and [Check if class is a template specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762958/check-if-class-is-a-template-specialization#31763111) I created the following variant to check for specific instantiations of `MyClass1`, `MyClass2` or `MyClass3`:

```cpp
template <class T, template <class...> class Template>
constexpr bool is_instance_of_v = false;

template <template <class...> class Template, class... Args>
constexpr bool is_instance_of_v<Template<Args...>, Template> = true;

template<class T> struct MyClass1 { };
template<class T, class B> struct MyClass2 { };
template<class T, bool B> struct MyClass3 { };


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    constexpr bool b1 = is_instance_of_v<MyClass1<float>, MyClass1>;
    constexpr bool b2 = is_instance_of_v<MyClass1<float>, MyClass2>;
    // constexpr bool b3 = is_instance_of_v<MyClass1<float>, MyClass3>;  // <-- does not compile

    return 0;
}
```

However, the code for `b3` does not compile & gives the following error:

```
error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'MyClass3' does not match the 
                 template parameter list for template parameter 'Template'
error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
```

It seems this is because the `bool` argument from `MyClass3` is not a `class`, and thus cannot be captured via `template <class...> class Template`.

Is there a way to fix this so that it works for any list of template arguments (not just `class`, but also `bool`, `int`, etc.)?

Comment: Without making `is_instance_of_v` a macro (so the template does not need to be passed as template template parameter), I don't think that is currently possible.

Comment: There are no common templates to handle type parameters and non type parameters.

Comment: No, as far I know. C++17 introduced `auto` for a generic template value. You needs something as `auto` but more powerful: something that can intercept a generic template parameter: type, value or template-template. Unfortunately, there isn't, in C++ language, such super-`auto`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unify type and non-type template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342064/unify-type-and-non-type-template-parameters)

Comment: I have to tend to agree with what others have said, that there is no possible implementation; but you might want to see if lambdas could possibly help you here. I wouldn't hold your breath but it might be worth trying or looking into it. Maybe in C++20 with concepts, there might be a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no common templates to handle type parameters and non type parameters (and template template parameters).